# How to be able to update prop from child or parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a customized ListBox component that displays a list of items with checkboxes.  It looks like this:

```
interface IListBox {
  itemList: Array<string>;
  selectedValues: Array<string> | null;
  onChange?: (values: Array<string>) => void;
}

const ListBox = ({ itemList, selectedValues, onChange }: IListBox => {
  // Much code here
};
```

Now, if I allow only one-way updates of the checkboxes - via the user checking/unchecking the checkboxes in the component, then all works fine: the `onChange` callback function is called with the latest checked values, which passes them up to the parent component, and all remains in sync.

However, what I'd now like to be able to do is also alter the value of `selectedValues` from the parent component - to clear them, for example, or to be able to set a certain combination of them at any point.  But when I've tried doing this in several different ways, things go haywire.

How would you go about allowing the parent component to alter the content of `selectedValues` in the child component?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--`ListBox` currently receives `selectedValues` as a property. If that value is changed correctly `ListBox` should re-render.

Comment: Can you add parent code as well. meaning how do you want to update these value in parent ?